# how to call the deepest parentheses python

Tags: printing

I'm trying to do this example :

```
sentence="{My name is {Adam} and I don't work here}"
```

Result should be `'Adam'`

So what I'm trying to say is however many parenthesis exist I want the result to show the value of the last closed parenthesis

Comment: Are you trying to replace {adam} with the `input()` command?

Comment: If you're trying to find the innermost parentheses you could try looking at the number of open and closing parenthesis.

Comment: Your try doesn't attempt to detect any parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but if there can only ever be one set of outer braces at any level (i.e. `"{My name} {is {Adam}}"` and `"{My {name} is {Adam}}"` are invalid input), you can take advantage of the fact that what you want is the last opening brace in the sentence.

```
def deepest(sentence):
     intermediate = sentence.rpartition("{")[-1]
     return intermediate[:intermediate.index("}")]

deepest("{My name is {Adam} and I don't work here}")
# 'Adam'
deepest("{Someone {set us {{up} the bomb}!}}")
# 'up'
```

The regex answer also makes this assumption, though regex is likely to be much slower. If multiple outer braces are possible, please make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just index strings like that... The best way is to use a clever regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'{[^{}]*}', "{My name is {Adam} and I don't work here}").group()
'{Adam}'
```

This regex pattern essentially searches for every set of `{}` that doesn't have the characters `{` or `}` in them.